# unifdef for Makefiles?

Tags: linux, makefile

Is there an equivalent to the [unifdef program](http://dotat.at/prog/unifdef/) that works on Makefiles?  I'd like to automate removal of certain features from Makefiles as well as source files.  I would think that the two would go hand in hand, but so far I can't seem to find anything.

Comment: `unifdef`? Do you mean `#undef`? Also, possible duplicate of [Can Make undefine a variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1473250/can-make-undefine-a-variable)

Comment: You'll have to give us a clearer idea of what you're trying to do, if we're to have any chance of helping you. Do you want to remove some members from a list of source files? Undefine variables? Deactivate rules from an `include`d makefile?

Comment: unifdef is a program that modifies C code.  It removes, or leaves in portions of code protected by #if expressions.   So, for example, you can tell it YYY is undefined, and it would remove a block of code protected by "#if defined(YYY) && defined(XXX) ... #endif" (including the #if and #endif).  What I want is a program that does this for makefiles that would operate on ifeq(YYY,), statements within a Makefile.

Comment: I, too, would like to know of a program that can rewrite GNU makefiles.  Of course nothing prevents you from running a preprocessor such as `cpp` or `m4` on your own makefiles, like the GNU autotools do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The unifdef program already works on makefiles (or any other text file), with the caveat that since the #ifdef#endif statements will be treated as comments by make, the "raw" file will go through all of your statemens. I use unifdef on makefiles mainly for the following purpose: In my code I have blocks that are only used in development and that for reason of being sloppy or for being possibly dangerous I don't want to have in the published code. By using unifdef on both sourcecode and makefiles, I can get a publishable codebase from my development code, without having to sync by development code with a public branch or similar. I can also use unifdef to get code, including buildscripts and makefiles, targeted at different platforms or audiences using this method, though since the #ifdef statements are parsed as comments, using e.g. #else can be a bit tricky, and too advanced applications of this technique will probably become unmaintainable fairly quickly.

Comment: I ended up writing a script which parsed comments.   It ended up needing to be a bit more powerful so I couldn't just use unifdef.   I will mark this as accepted, as it is correct.